# Writing a MySQL query that counts entries uniquely

Tags: mysql

This is my table structure-

```
TABLE : T_LOG

---------------------------------------------------
 |    ID    |   AREA     |  USER_ID |   DATE
---------------------------------------------------
 |     1    |   AREA1    |     5    |  2000-05-17
---------------------------------------------------
 |     2    |   AREA1    |     5    |  2002-12-12
---------------------------------------------------
 |     3    |   AREA2    |     5    |  2003-02-19
---------------------------------------------------
 |     4    |   AREA1    |     5    |  2006-05-22
---------------------------------------------------
 |     5    |   AREA2    |     5    |  2006-07-29
---------------------------------------------------
 |     6    |   AREA3    |     5    |  2009-05-07
---------------------------------------------------
```

In this table `USER_ID` `5` has been to several `AREA`s at several `DATE`s.
I want to pick how many (uniquely) `AREA`s the particular `USER_ID` has been to so far.

The following query

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T_LOG WHERE USER_ID = 5 GROUP BY 'AREA'`

returns 6 as in 6 entries. But I want it to return 3 as in 3 Areas uniquely (`AREA1`, `AREA2`, `AREA3`)

How do I correct this query?

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` in the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use count (distinct):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT AREA) FROM T_LOG WHERE USER_ID = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Your actual problem is that you have specified `Area` column as a value in the `GROUP BY` clause (i.e. `GROUP BY 'Area'`). Which should be without single quotes. (i.e. `GROUP BY Area`)

So try this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T_LOG WHERE USER_ID = 5 GROUP BY AREA
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7aeb8/6)

Alternatively you can directly use `COUNT(DISTINCT Area)` as already mentioned in other answers (which one is more preferable).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT AREA), USER_ID FROM T_LOG WHERE USER_ID = 5
```

Comment: column name must not be wrapped with single quotes.